# How to take an arbitrary proto message as input and call protojson.Marshal with it

Tags: go, proto

I'm writing a function that takes an arbitrary proto message and does something with it

```
func protoToSomething(in proto.Message) ([]byte, error) {
    jsonBytes, protoJsonError := protojson.Marshal(in)
    if protoJsonError != nil {
        return nil, protoJsonError
    }
   stuff here...
}
```

However when I call it with this:

```
    model := myprotolib.MyRequest{
        UserId:        "3214",
        UserName:      "JohnDoe",
        SomeValue:     true,
    }
    data, _ := protoToSomething(model)
```

I get this "myprotolib.MyRequest does not implement protoreflect.ProtoMessage (ProtoReflect method has pointer receiver)"

This looks accurate because when I look at the autogenerated proto code, it is defined with

```
func (x *MyRequest) ProtoReflect() protoreflect.Message {
```

(Where the receiver takes a pointer.)

But when I look at the definition in protoreflect/proto.go I see

```
type ProtoMessage interface{ ProtoReflect() Message }
```

So I'm confused, and new to Go (though I've used Protos, Java, and C++ professionally) -- how do I write a function that takes an arbitrary proto message and does some stuff to it, including protojson.Marshall?

Comment: Use `protoToSomething(&model)`

Comment: Thanks @BurakSerdar that worked but can you help me understand why? model isn't a reference, and the function protoToSomething takes a real proto.Message, so why shouldn't what I had work?

Answer (score 1):

`model` does not implement that interface, because `model` declared that method for a pointer receiver.

If a method is declared with a pointer receiver, only pointers of that type implement that interface, not the value types. That is:

```
type I interface {
   f()
}

type S struct {
}

func (s S) f() {}

type T struct {
}

func (t *T) f() {}

func W(intf I) {}

func main() {
   s:=S{}
   W(s)  // This works. S has method f()
   W(&s) // This works. *S has method f()
   t:=T{}
   W(t) // This does not work. T does not have f()
   w(&t) // This works. *T has f()
}
```

This essentially prevents inadvertently passing a copy of a value where a pointer is needed.

Comment: Why wouldn't Go just automatically send the pointer to the pointer receiver, the same way it automatically dereferences a pointer when the receiver function expects a value?

Comment: If you call `t.f()`, then `f` will receive the address of `t`, so it does send the pointer receiver automatically. This case is different. You are passing a struct as an interface. The syntax `W(t)` means you're passing a copy of `t`, not address of it.